# Searching Multiple Tables and Returning/Mapping a Dynamic Result Set

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I have a mySql schema named Contacts that contains 4 tables: Contacts, Phone, Email, and Addresses. The Contacts table contains basic information about a person such as an id number, first name, and last name. The other tables all contain a foreign key that links it to the Contacts table so for example, John Doe in the Contacts table can have multiple phone numbers in the Phones table that are all searchable by using John Doe's id number.

My question is how do I query this schema and return all data for a single (or multiple) users. Can it be done with one SQL statement, or do I need to contact the database for each individual table based on the fact that the amount of results returned will not match for each row returned from the Contacts table. For example, I have some basic search functionality that searches the Contacts table for one or more rows based on search criteria:

```
public class ContactsListDAO {
//Constants
private static final String SQL_FIND_BY_SEARCH_CRITERIA = "SELECT * FROM Contacts.Contacts WHERE Id LIKE :searchString OR FirstName LIKE :searchString OR LastName LIKE :searchString";

//Variables
private DAOFactory daoFactory;
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

//Constructors
public ContactsListDAO(DAOFactory daoFactory) {
    this.daoFactory = daoFactory;
    this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(daoFactory.getDataSource());
}

public List<Contact> findSearchResults(String searchCriteria) {
    Map<String, String> namedParameters = Collections.singletonMap("searchString", searchCriteria);

    RowMapper<Contact> mapper = new RowMapper<Contact>() {
        @Override
        public Contact mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int row) throws SQLException {
            Contact contact = new Contact(
                    resultSet.getInt("Id"),
                    resultSet.getString("FirstName"),
                    resultSet.getString("LastName")
                );
            return contact;
        }           
    };

    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(SQL_FIND_BY_SEARCH_CRITERIA, namedParameters, mapper);
}
}
```

I am using spring to query and map the results back to a Contact bean. How would I go about modifying this SQL statement and mapping functionality to search the contacts table, get the data for each row and then based on the id of each returned row, also query the phone, email, and address tables and then map those to a List object stored in the bean? The problem is that row 1's id might find 8 phone numbers rows that match the id, but row 2's id might only find 3 phone numbers. How is this going to be stored in a ResultSet? Or will I have to query the Contacts table first and then perform a separate query for each other table (for each row returned from the first) and add that data to the bean case by case? If the first query returns 100 results, and I have to perform a query for each of those on 3 tables, I am looking at 301 trips to the database and back.

Is it possible to use one query and just return 1 result from each of the phone, email, address tables for each result found in the Contacts table? Maybe I can add a primary column or something so it only returns 1 result and then if the user clicks something to request more information about the result it can perform the other queries and gather all the info about that user.

Comment: Do you use Ibatis as sql Adapter? if yes, you can use the "Result Map with a Complex Property" to store one property on result map as a List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query i've come up with uses LEFT JOIN to search the tables:

```
SELECT * FROM Contacts.Contacts LEFT JOIN Contacts.Phone ON Contacts.Id = Phone.ContactId AND Phone.Primary = 1 LEFT JOIN Contacts.Email ON Contacts.Id = Email.ContactId AND Email.Primary = 1 WHERE Contacts.Id LIKE :searchString OR Contacts.FirstName LIKE :searchString OR Contacts.LastName LIKE :searchString AND Contacts.OrganizationId = :organizationId
```

I created a column in the Phone, Email, and Address database called Primary that contains a boolean so that on my initial query I will only return 1 result for each Contact in the database. So far this is doing what I need. Not sure if it the proper way to go about something like this?